# Ordering a found set by number of times a user has viewed the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to order a list of locations based on the number of times a user has viewed them. Am using the impressionist gem for the sake of it.

The problem I'm having is that my query completely excludes those locations the user's never viewed. I need to display these at the bottom of the results and order by the created_at timestamp.

I can do this to get a list of location_ids:

```
 @location_ids = @user.impressions.
   select('count(id) as counter, impressionable_id').
   group(:impressionable_id).
   order('counter DESC').

 @location_ids.map(&:impressionable_id)
```

Which gives [3,5,8,44,99] and so on..

However, that doesn't get me far so I tried this:

```
 @user.locations.
  joins(:impressions).
  select("count(impressions.id) as counter, impressionable_id, locations.location_name, locations.id").
  group(:impressionable_id).
  order("counter desc")
```

Which is better but it omits those locations with zero views.

How should I do this to get all the locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Rails uses an `inner join` when you use `.joins`. That's why you don't see the locations with no associated impressions. You need to tell it to use a `left join` instead, probably like so:

```
 @user.locations.
  joins("left join impressions on impressions.impressionable_id = locations.id and impressions.impressionable_type = 'Location'").
  select("count(impressions.id) as counter, impressionable_id, locations.location_name, locations.id").
  group('locations.id').
  order("counter desc")
```

Comment: Hey MrTheWalrus. That's giving a single location as the output.

Comment: If I remove 'impressions.impressionable_type = 'Location'' I get the locations in the correct order but I'm still missing the blanks.

Comment: Ah. Found the problem (I think). You're grouping by `impressions.impressionable_id` instead of `locations.id`, which is going to be `NULL` for all the ones that don't have any impressions. Not sure exactly what that would do (I'm used to PostGres, which would complain if I tried it), but it might well be causing the problem..

Comment: Evening. Much fiddling later and I reached the same conclusion. It's actually working a treat now. Have marked it as solved and many thanks for the assistance. S